# Trying to parse a JSON key in Teradata, but the query fails

Tags: json, teradata

I have a field called `JSON_VALUE` is my database. I'm trying the get the value for one of the keys in the JSON called `book`. It exists in every record and is unique.

The query I created, with help of Teradata manual:

```
SELECT JSONGETVALUE(NEW JSON(JSON_VALUE, LATIN), '$.book' AS VARCHAR) FROM BOOK_TABLE
```

This fails with an error: `The string contains an untranslatable character.`

I tried checking whether my JSON is valid with JSON_CHECK, but it showed OK for each record.

Am I doing something wrong or missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Is the JSON data in UTF8 or UTF16? What’s the table definition including the JSON column definition?

Comment: I eventually fixed this by changing LATIN to UNICODE. Don't know what is the difference though.

Comment: If you fixed it that way, it means the data in your table is stored as unicode.  That parameter tells the JSONGetValue function how the data is encoded.